# Why are all of my shapes stuck in the top left of my JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, shapes

I've created a JPanel full of circles, lines and rectangles that are supposed to randomly spawn all around the JPanel, however the circles and rectangles only show up in the top left corner of the JPanel instead of randomly throughout the JPanel, while the lines work perfectly.  I was wondering if anyone could help me out?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 *
 * 
 */
public class RandomShapesPanel extends JPanel
{
    private Color rColor;
    private Random rGen;
    private Random num;

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    int x = this.getWidth();
    int y = getHeight();
    int x1, y1, x2, y2;
    rGen = new Random();
    num = new Random();
    for(int i = 1; i <= 35; i++)
    {
        rColor = new Color(rGen.nextInt(256),rGen.nextInt(256),
                rGen.nextInt(256));
        g.setColor(rColor);
        x1 = rGen.nextInt(x - 1) + 1;
        x2 = rGen.nextInt(x - 1) + 1;
        y1 = rGen.nextInt(y - 1) + 1;
        y2 = rGen.nextInt(y - 1) + 1;
        g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
    for(int i = 1; i <= 35; i++)
    {
        rColor = new Color(rGen.nextInt(256),rGen.nextInt(256),
                rGen.nextInt(256));
        g.setColor(rColor);
        x1 = num.nextInt(50) + 10;
        x2 = num.nextInt(50) + 10;
        y1 = num.nextInt(50) + 10;
        y2 = num.nextInt(50) + 10;
        g.drawRect(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
    for(int i = 1; i <= 35; i++)
    {
        rColor = new Color(rGen.nextInt(256),rGen.nextInt(256),
                rGen.nextInt(256));
        g.setColor(rColor);
        x1 = num.nextInt(50) + 10;
        x2 = num.nextInt(50) + 10;
        y1 = num.nextInt(50) + 10;
        y2 = num.nextInt(50) + 10;
        g.fillRect(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
    for(int i = 1; i <= 35; i++)
    {
        rColor = new Color(rGen.nextInt(256),rGen.nextInt(256),
                rGen.nextInt(256));
        g.setColor(rColor);
        x1 = num.nextInt(50) + 10;
        x2 = num.nextInt(50) + 10;
        y1 = num.nextInt(50) + 10;
        y2 = num.nextInt(50) + 10;
        g.drawOval(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
    for(int i = 1; i <= 35; i++)
    {
        rColor = new Color(rGen.nextInt(256),rGen.nextInt(256),
                rGen.nextInt(256));
        g.setColor(rColor);
        x1 = num.nextInt(50) + 10;
        x2 = num.nextInt(50) + 10;
        y1 = num.nextInt(50) + 10;
        y2 = num.nextInt(50) + 10;
        g.fillOval(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh come on now this should be obvious -- look how you're calling nextInt differently for the lines, the rectangles and the circles

Comment: Is this your code, or did you borrow code that you don't understand?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to define these like this:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 35; i++)
{
    rColor = new Color(rGen.nextInt(256),rGen.nextInt(256),
            rGen.nextInt(256));
    g.setColor(rColor);
    x1 = num.nextInt(x-50) + 10;
    x2 = num.nextInt(50) + 10;
    y1 = num.nextInt(y-50) + 10;
    y2 = num.nextInt(50) + 10;
    g.drawRect(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}
```